# Google Drive API - get list of files including folders

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I need to list all images in a users drive cloud.

I use  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files with the correct filter to query all images. I need to group the result in my app in folders. I know a file can have multiple parents, that's fine.

I would like to avoid making and calls (for every single file a single call) to get a files folder via https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get using the parent id from the first call.

*Is there a network friendly way to get all files inclusive there folders?*

**EDIT**

A simple solution would be to get all folders with ids in one query and lookup folder names in this result. Maybe that's somehow possible?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. Yes it's possible.

Comment: Currently testing that, with a filter I can get folders only and put them in a map and recursively look up the folder parents and construct the paths like that...

Comment: Personally I would avoid recursion - it can loop because there is no guarantee that the folders form a hierarchy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you answered yourself in the comments above (but you can't match names, you have to match IDs; names aren't unique).

**Step 1**: get all your folders in one shot (paging results, filtering unneeded fields, skipping the trashed ones):

```
  private static Drive mGOOSvc;
  ....
  static ArrayList<ContentValues> getFolders() {
    ArrayList<ContentValues> cvs = new ArrayList<>();
    if (mGOOSvc != null) try {
      Drive.Files.List qry = mGOOSvc.files().list()
        .setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'")
        .setFields("items(id,labels/trashed,parents/id,title),nextPageToken");
      String npTok = null;
      if (qry != null) do {
        FileList gLst = qry.execute();
        if (gLst != null) {
          for (File gFl : gLst.getItems()) {
            if (gFl.getLabels().getTrashed()) continue;
            for (ParentReference parent : gFl.getParents())
              cvs.add(newContentValues(gFl.getTitle(), gFl.getId(), parent.getId()));
          }
          npTok = gLst.getNextPageToken();
          qry.setPageToken(npTok);
        }
      } while (npTok != null && npTok.length() > 0);
    } catch (Exception e) { /* handle Exceptions */ }
    return cvs;
  }
```

**Step 2**: Parse the resulting ArrayList to build the tree structure (match ParentIds, handle multiple parents)

**Step 3**: Do the same for files with mime type ""image/jpeg", "image/png", ... "whatever img mimetype" (just modify the code above to get files) and parse again.

Of course the 'execute()' method will produce exceptions  that should be handled as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968921/google-drive-rest-api-on-android/33970272#33970272).

... and you can take the '*not so network friendly*' approach of iterating down the folder tree as seen in the 'testTree()' method [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/MainActivity.java). Recursion is necessary if you have no knowledge how deep your tree structure is.

Good Luck

Comment: Good answer, but remember that Google Drive isn't a tree structure. It's a network.

Comment: looks like what I do (I don't use the sdk, I use `scribe` and the direct oauth approach with direct api calls, as I want to include many networks and keep the app small). Thanks, this will help others as well. As I'm no drive user, I could not find out how a file gets multiple parents. I have folder where I can store my files in and options to move files, but nothing that let's my put one file into multiple directories, at least I can't find anything... But I now handle multiple parents as well... Btw, you can filter out trashed items in the query itself before retrieving files as well

Comment: GooDrive is a network model. Just a pile of objects with pointers (nothing points to files, though, only folders are pointed to). Different from classic OS. Leads to 'unusual' scenarios, like "what happens when you delete an object that has multiple parents?", since in http://drive.google.com (like in classic tree) you delete one instance you found under one parent... You just have to adjust your head around it. Difficult to translate to a logic meaningful to non-geeky users, though.

Comment: @prom85 "I could not find out how a file gets multiple parents" Your app can certainly force it in 'create' or 'patch'. And I think the 'copy' action on http://drive.google.com may as well, but not sure about it. Could be tested in 'Try It' [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) (bottom of the page).